# Limiting function of $f_n(x) = e^{-nx}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $f_n: [0, 3] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n(x) = e^{-nx}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N_1}$
>
> Determine the limiting function $f:[0, 3] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$

I know that $e^{-nx} \rightarrow 0$, when $n \rightarrow \infty$, but how do we show this rigorously with the exponential function?

Edit: My assumption doesn't hold when $x = 0$ as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Careful: $e^{-nx} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$ if $x>0$, but not when $x=0$.

Comment: Fix any $x_0\in[0,3]$. If $x_0>0$, then the sequence $(e^{-nx_0})_n$ converges to... Now, if $x_0=0$, then... Therefore, the sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ converges pointwise to... The exponential does not complicate things here. You still have to analyze sequences.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake! @CliveNewstead

Comment: Could you elaborate on as to why it convergences pointwise also when $x_0 = 0$? Doesn't pointwise convergence assume that the limit is defined within the whole domain? @ClementC.

Comment: @Daniel When $x_0=0$, $f_n(x_0) = e^{-n \cdot 0} = e^0 = 1$ for all $n$. This is a constant sequence, so it immediately converges.

Comment: Note that the limit function is not continuous, so the convergence is not uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the limit rigorously, let $x>0$ be fixed and $\epsilon>0$. Then solving 
$$
e^{-nx}<\epsilon \implies -nx<\ln(\epsilon) \implies n>-\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{x}
$$
Hence, choose $N=\lceil-\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{x}\rceil$. Then for all  $n\geq N$, we have $e^{-nx}<\epsilon$. This limit cannot be made uniform on $(0,3]$ since as $x\to 0$, the formula for $N\to\infty$.

Comment: Just to clarify. The resulting limiting function $f(x)$ in this case is $f(x) =   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1, & x = 0 \\
      0, & 0 < x\leq 3  \\
\end{array} 
\right.$ right?

Comment: That is correct.